# Why gcc does so when creating assembler code?

Tags: gcc, assembly

I am playing around with `gcc -S` to understand how memory and stack works. During these plays I found several things unclear to me. Could you please help me to understand the reasons?

1. When calling function sets arguments for a called one it uses `mov` to `esp` instead `push`. What is the advantage not using `push`?
2. Function which works with its stack located arguments points to them as `ebp + (N + offset)` (where N is a size reserved for return address). I expect to see `esp - offset` which is more understandable. What is the reason to use `ebp` as fundamental point everywhere? I know these ones are equal but anyway?
3. What is this magic for in the beginning of `main`? Why `esp` must be initialized in this way only?

   ```
   and    esp,0xfffffff0
   ```

Thanks,

Comment: This could be 3 separate questions. Anyways, the answer to the 3rd point is stack alignment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will assume you are working under a 32-bit environment because in a 64-bit environment arguments are passed in registers.

Question 1

Perhaps you are passing a floating point argument here.  You cannot push these directly, as the `push` instruction in a 32-bit runtime pushes 4 bytes at a time so you would have to break up the value.  It is sometimes easier to subtract 8 from `esp` and them mov the 8-byte quadword into `[esp]`.

Question 2

`ebp` is frequently used to index the parameters and locals in stack frames in 32-bit code.  This allows the offsets within frames to be fixed even as the stack pointer moves.  For example consider

```
void f(int x) {
    int a;
    g(x, 5);
}
```

Now if you only accessed the stack frame contents with `esp`, then `a` is at `[esp]`, the return address would be at `[esp+4]` and `x` would be at `[esp+8]`.  Now let's generate code to call `g`.  We have to first push 5 then push `x`.  But after pushing 5, the offset of `x` from `esp` has changed!  This is why `ebp` is used.  Normally on entry to functions we push the old value of `ebp` to save it, then copy `esp` to `ebp`.  Now `ebp` can be used to access stack frame contents.  It won't move when we are in the middle of passing arguments.

Question 3

This `and` instruction zeros out the last 4 bits of `esp`, aligning it to a 16-byte boundary.  Since the stack grows downward, this is nice and safe.

Comment: Q3: It zeros out the last 4 bits

Comment: Oh my, thanks, @drhirsch.  Typing without thinking.  Terrible.  Thanks so much!  Edited.